# TYPO3 6.1/6.2 - Extend existing domain model

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am trying to extend an existing domain model with a new field, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I tried the following with both TYPO3 6.1 and TYPO3 6.2 (latest versions, Extension Builder git master branch).

1. Create new extension with extension builder (vendor: TEST, extension key: mytest1)
2. Create a new table with the name "table1"
3. Create a new propery for table1 called "title1"
4. Save extension
5. Install extension

Until now, everything works as expected. I can create record in TYPO3 backend for "table1" records and enter a property for "title1"

Now I want to extend the extension "mytest1" with a new field. I must do this with a new extension, so I do the following:

1. Create another extension with extension builder (vendor: TEST, extension key: mytest2)
2. Create a new table with the name "table1"
3. In the field "Extend existing model class" I enter the class "\TEST\Mytest1\Domain\Model\Table1"
4. Create a new property called "title2"
5. Save extension
6. Install extension

I would now expect, that I have 2 fields in TYPO3 backend for the record "table1". Actually, I just have the one field "title1" I created in the extension "mytest1".

As far as I can see, both ext_tables.php and "ext_typoscript_setup.txt" look fine. TCA is extended by the extra field and also the extbase record type seems to be ok. Also "table1" contains the new field added by "mytest2" ext_tables.sql. It is just, that the TCA does'nt seem to be loaded.

When I try the same with TYPO3 4.5 and ExtensionBuilder, everything works as expected.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tempColumns = array(
    'title2' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'title2',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input'
        )
    )
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('table1', $tempColumns, 1);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('table1', 'title2;;;;1-1-1');
```

This should be enough to add a field to an existing table in TCA. Have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It pointed me to the right direction (see my answer/explaination below) and resulted in the new field to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Extension Builder seems to create wrong ext_tables.php

When I do the extension creation as described above, it extends the TCA with both the new field and the field tx_extbase_type. So far, so good. The last line in ext_tables.php is the most important one, where addToAllTCAtypes is called.

Extension Builder creates the following function call:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tx_mytest1_domain_model_table1', $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_mytest1_domain_model_table1']['ctrl']['type'],'','after:' . $TCA['tx_mytest1_domain_model_table1']['ctrl']['label']);
```

The last parameter (which is $postition) is wrong. It tries to add the new TCA config after the value configured in **$TCA['tx_test1_domain_model_table1']['ctrl']['label']** which actually is empty (because not defined in mytest1 extension).

If this parameter points to something that does not exist (e.g. "after:nonexistingfield"), then the new TCA configuration is **completely ignored** and not added.

I replaced the addToAllTCAtypes call with the following:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tx_mytest1_domain_model_table1', $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_mytest1_domain_model_table1']['ctrl']['type'],'','');
```

I just left the $position parameter empty, which results in that the two new fields (title2 and tx_extbase_type) are being shown in the form in the backend (actually in a new tab as Extension Builder creates a --div-- in the showitem configuration for the new fields).

You can also point the position to an existing field (e.g. "after:title1") and the new field tx_extbase_type is then shown after the title1 field.

I believe this is a bug in Extension Builder and will file an issue on forge.